# iOS wired freezing issue on changing view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have an iOS app with two way of changing and navigation between view controllers, the first way is by using push/pop with navigation controller and the second one is a custom way of transition using Custom Container View Controller from apple documentation,

**here is the storyboard screen shot:**

[image]

**and in the ViewController.swift:**

```
var contentViewController: UIViewController! {
    didSet {
        // remove any previous views
        for view in self.contentView.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // add the view
        // the ViewController must be aded to the children list to avoid being released (as it become a Zombie)
        self.addChildViewController(self.contentViewController)

        if registerDoneFlag {

            //do some animation
            let animation =  CATransition()
            animation.duration = 0.3
            animation.type = kCATransitionPush
            animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

            self.contentView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "SwitchToView1")

            registerDoneFlag = false
        }
        if backFlag {

            //do some animation
            let animation =  CATransition()
            animation.duration = 0.3
            animation.type = kCATransitionPush
            animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

            self.contentView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "SwitchToView1")

            backFlag = false
        }

        self.contentView.addSubview(self.contentViewController.view)
        self.contentViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
}
```

**and we are doing these animations on the beginning of the app:**

```
func upperViewAnimation() {

    contianerTop.constant = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.45, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion:{(finished)  in

            if finished {

                if noInternetConnection && !noInternetConnectionPopup {

                    if isiPadFlag {

                        self.noConnectionViewHeight.constant = 60
                    }
                    else {

                        self.noConnectionViewHeight.constant = 50
                    }

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {

                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    })

                    noInternetConnectionPopup = true

                    openNoInternetConnection()

                }
                else if noInternetConnection {

                    if isiPadFlag {

                        self.noConnectionViewHeight.constant = 60
                    }
                    else {

                        self.noConnectionViewHeight.constant = 50
                    }

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {

                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    })

                }
                else {

                    self.noConnectionViewHeight.constant = 0

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {

                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                        }, completion: { (finished) in

                            self.pullToRefreshAction()

                    })


                }

                self.notificationButtonAnimationAndMenuButton()
                self.moreAppsLabel.hidden = false
            }

    })

    //self.notificationButtonAnimationAndMenuButton()

}
```

every thing is working fine except in some cases app enter in a wired freezing situation, the navigation way work fine (push/pop) but the changing view controller way is not working at all even the app execute the did set of contentViewController but no render no changes with the app

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar behavior when main thread was engaged to execute service/web requests during complete view load process.

Comment: hi thank you for your answer, but what do you mean by "during complete view load process" :)